# Can I add a variable name to itertools list?

Tags: python, python-itertools

This will print all of the possible combinations:

```
import itertools
iterables = [[0,1,2], ["3","46","5"]]
for item in itertools.product(*iterables, repeat=1):
    print(item)
```

like:

```
0,3
0,46
0,5
1,3
etc.
```

Suppose "A" has the values `[0,1,2]` and "B" has `["3", "46", "5]`,
can I modify the code that the print will be something like:

```
A 0
B 3
A 0
B 46
A 1
B 3
```

etc.?

or any other way where the variable name is also part of the results?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `print("A {} B {}".format(*item))`?

Comment: "A {}\nB {}" :p

Answer (score 2):

Flatten the list of tuples, and zip it with the repeating sequence of explicit variable names.

```
from itertools import chain, cycle, product

for var, value in zip(cycle(["A", "B"]),
                      chain.from_iterable(product(*iterables))):
    print(var, value)
```

`chain.from_iterable` turns something like `(x, y), (x, y)` into `x, y, x, y`. `cycle([x,y])` produces `x, y, x, y, ...`. The cycle is infinite, but `zip` only consumes as much as needed to exhaust the flattened product sequence.